# WebView is empty in React Native

Tags: react-native, webview, expo

Problem. The WebView is empty in React Native. However, the link works.
The code :

```js
import React from 'react';
import { StyleSheet, View, WebView } from 'react-native';
import { Constants } from 'expo';

export default class App extends React.Component {

  render() {
    return (
    <View>
    <View style={styles.statusBar} />
     <WebView
        source={{uri: 'https://lapommeculturelle.com'}}
        renderError={() => alert('Merci de vérifier votre connexion Internet - Internet non disponible')}
      />
    </View>
    );
  }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  statusBar: {
    backgroundColor: "#1D3B57",
    height: Constants.statusBarHeight,
  }
});
```

For this project, I used Expo XDE. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At the bare minimum, you need a style for the `View` that wraps the rest of them.

I'd recommend `<View style={{flex: 1}}>` just to get you started.
In an ideal world, you'd make that a style associated with your container and be pulling it from your `StyleSheet`:

```
import React from 'react';
import { StyleSheet, Text, View, WebView, ActivityIndicator } from 'react-native';
import { Constants } from 'expo';


export default class App extends React.Component {

  render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <View style={styles.statusBar} />
        <WebView
          source={{uri: 'https://lapommeculturelle.com'}}
          renderError={() => alert('Merci de vérifier votre connexion Internet', 'Internet non disponible')}
        />
      </View>
    );
  }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
  },
  statusBar: {
    backgroundColor: "#1D3B57",
    height: Constants.statusBarHeight,
  }
});
```

Answer (score 4):

I believe you need to be specifying the height and width of the webview, as well as specifying the flex for the wrapping view. 
Try this:

```
<View style={{flex:1}}>
<View style={styles.statusBar} />
 <WebView
    style={{height: 300, width: 300}}
    source={{uri: 'https://lapommeculturelle.com'}}
    renderError={() => alert('Merci de vérifier votre connexion Internet', 'Internet non disponible')}
  />
</View>
```

Answer (score 0):

My fix for iOS, for some reason, is this `style`:

```js
<WebView
  // fixes warning when page has an iframe (about:srcdoc)
  originWhitelist={['http://*', 'https://*', 'about:srcdoc']}
  renderLoading={this._renderLoadingWebView}
  scrollEnabled
  source={{ uri }}
  style={{ borderWidth: 1, borderColor: 'transparent' }}
/>
```

`react-native-webview 7.5.2`